# UK postcode to Index of Multiple deprivation

Tags: postal-code, ons-api

I want to get the Index of Multiple Deprivation value for a given (UK) postcode. It can be done using the tool developed by an Oxford group (link below)

http://tools.npeu.ox.ac.uk/imd/

I want to know what the conversion process is. I know the iMDs are only designed for an area (ie: LSOA code). So does that mean that we have to convert to postcode to a LSOA code first?

A related question is to find the postcodes for a given area. Say how can I find if a postcode belongs to London or Birmingham? Or how can find if a postcode belongs the redbridge area of London?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the old Ness Data Exchange service (XML response only). This call gives you the LSOA for a postcode:

http://neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/NDE2/Disco/FindAreas?Postcode=PO155RR&LevelTypeId=141&HierarchyId=26

For other areas, you need to do some extra discovery calls in the browser to get the hierarchy and leveltype ids. For example if you wanted Westminster Parliamentary Constituencies...

http://neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/NDE2/Disco/GetHierarchies

http://neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/NDE2/Disco/GetLevelTypesByHierarchy?HierarchyId=28

http://neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/NDE2/Disco/FindAreas?Postcode=PO155RR&LevelTypeId=27&HierarchyId=28

An alternative is to use ArcGIS, which I described here [Getting data for LSOA via the ons API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153682/getting-data-for-lsoa-via-the-ons-api)